# Json error : "end is out of bounds"?

Tags: python, json

I'm having an issue I can't understand. I sending a json data as string via Redis (as a queue) and the receiver is throwing the following error :

```
[ERROR JSON (in queue)] - {"ip": null, "domain": "somedomain.com", "name": "Some user name", "contact_id": 12345, "signature": 
"6f496a4eaba2c1ea4e371ea2c4951ad92f41ddf45ff4949ffa761b0648a22e38"} => end is out of bounds
```

The code that throws the exception is the following :

```
try:
    item = json.loads(item[1])
except ValueError as e:
    sys.stderr.write("[ERROR JSON (in queue)] - {1} => {0}\n".format(str(e), str(item)))
    return None
```

What is really odd, is that if I open a python console and do the following :

```
>>> import json
>>> s = '{"ip": null, "domain": "somedomain.com", "name": "Some user name", "contact_id": 12345, "signature": "6f496a4eaba2c1ea4e371ea2c4951ad92f41ddf45ff4949ffa761b0648a22e38"}'
>>> print s
```

I have no issue, the string (copy/pasted in the Python console) yield no errors at all, but my original code is throwing one!

Do you have any idea about what is causing the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are loading `item[1]`, which is the second character of the string `items`:

```
>>> json.loads('"')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 381, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: end is out of bounds
```

You should write:

```
item = json.loads(item)
```

Comment: But what is really odd is that this issue occurs only a few times. `item` is a tuple containing the key from Redis in 0, and the value (the json data) in 1. Sometimes, the json value is in the full item, I don't know why.

Comment: this is not part of your question. You should ask a new question, why Redis returns a string instead of a tuple.

Comment: Yes you are right, and your answer is the right one for my question here, so I accepted it and upvoted tit.